# Working with very large numbers

Tags: math

Wikipedia says

> As of January 2016, the largest known prime number is **2<sup>74,207,281</sup> − 1**,
>   a number with **22,338,618 digits**.

and about PI:

> In September 2010, a Yahoo! employee used the company's Hadoop
>   application on one thousand computers over a 23-day period to compute
>   256 bits of π at the **two-quadrillionth (2×1015th) bit**, which also
>   happens to be zero.

Obviously I don't need use numbers with that magnitude, but just of curiosity, for the sake of the Science, How someone can work/generate so large numbers? Maybe when it is out of RAM, the app dumps all digits for disk, clean the memory and continues the process? And about the data type used to calculate it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Java classes [BigInteger](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/math/BigInteger.html) and [BigDecimal](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/index.html?java/math/BigDecimal.html) have arbitrary precision so that should work when the problem still fits in memory.

The fact that Yahoo! is using Hadoop for their Pi computation suggests that the digits may be stored to disk in a distributed manner using `HDFS`.

Answer (score 2):

One of the main projects looking for big prime numbers is the GIMPS (Great Internet Mersenne Prime Search). It uses a distributed software that you can install in your PC to help find those prime numbers.

In this case they are using C as their language as you can see on their GitHub project:
https://github.com/RWTH-ACS/GIMPS